# Python and Visual Studio Code: Pylance(reportUndefinedVariable)

Tags: python

I have the following Code:

```
import random

FONT_COLOUR = (255, 255, 255)
WIDTH = 800
HEIGHT = 600
CENTRE_X = WIDTH/2
CENTRE_Y = HEIGHT/2
CENTRE = (CENTRE_X, CENTRE_Y)
FINAL_LEVEL = 6
START_SPEED = 10
COLOURS = ["green", "blue"]

game_over = False
game_complete = False
current_level = 1
stars = []
animations = []

def draw():
    global stars, current_level, game_over, game_complete
    screen.clear()
    screen.blit("space", (0, 0))
    if game_over:
        display_message("GAME OVER!", "Versuche es erneut.")
    elif game_complete:
        display_message("DU HAST GEWONNEN!", "Gut gemacht.")
    else:
        for star in stars:
            star.draw()

def update():
    global stars
    if len(stars) == 0:
        stars = make_stars(current_level)

def make_stars(number_of_extra_stars):
    colours_to_create = get_colours_to_create(number_of_extra_stars)
    new_stars = create_stars(colours_to_create)
    layout_stars(new_stars)
    animate_stars(new_stars)
    return new_stars

def get_colours_to_create(number_of_extra_stars):
    colours_to_create = ["red"]
    for i in range(0, number_of_extra_stars):
        random_colour = random.choice(COLOURS)
        colours_to_create.append(random_colour)
    return colours_to_create


def create_stars(colours_to_create):
    new_stars = []
    for colour in colours_to_create:
        star = Actor(colour + "-star")
        new_stars.append(star)
        return new_stars

def layout_stars(stars_to_layout):
    number_of_gaps = len(stars_to_layout) + 1
    gap_size = WIDTH/number_of_gaps
    random.shuffle(stars_to_layout)
    for index, star in enumerate(stars_to_layout):
        new_x_pos = (index + 1) * gap_size
        star.x = new_x_pos

def animate_stars(stars_to_animate):
    for star in stars_to_animate:
        duration = START_SPEED - current_level
        star.anchor = ("center", "bottom")
        animation = animate(star, duration=duration, on_finished=handle_game_over, y=HEIGHT)
        animations.append(animation)

def handle_game_over():
    global game_over
    game_over = True

def on_mouse_down(pos):
    global stars, current_level
    for star in stars:
        if star.collidepoint(pos):
            if "red" in star.image:
                red_star_click()
            else:
                handle_game_over()
                
def red_star_click():
    global current_level, stars, animations, game_complete
    stop_animations(animations)
    if current_level == FINAL_LEVEL:
        game_complete = True
    else:
        current_level = current_level + 1
        stars = []
        animations = []
        
def stop_animations(animations_to_stop):
    for animation in animations_to_stop:
        if animation.running:
            animation.stop()
            
def display_message(heading_text, sub_heading_text):
    screen.draw.text(heading_text, fontsize=60, center=CENTRE, color=FONT_COLOUR)
    screen.draw.text(sub_heading_text,
                     fontsize=30,
                     center=(CENTRE_X, CENTRE_Y + 30),
                     color=FONT_COLOUR)
```

... and Visual Studio Code is presenting me the following problems:

- "screen" is not defined - Pylance(reportUndefinedVariable) [24,5]
- "screen" is not defined - Pylance(reportUndefinedVariable) [25,5]
- "Actor" is not defined - Pylance(reportUndefinedVariable) [57,16]
- "animate" is not defined - Pylance(reportUndefinedVariable) [73,21]
- "screen" is not defined - Pylance(reportUndefinedVariable) [105,5]
- "screen" is not defined - Pylance(reportUndefinedVariable) [106,5]

What can I do?

Comment: Define the variables!?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [ask]. It seems as if you have written, or copied, a large amount of code without really understanding how it is supposed to work. For example: In the `draw` function, where the code says `screen.clear()`, what do you expect that to mean? What do you expect `screen` to refer to at this point, and why? Where is the value supposed to come from? If you cannot answer a question like this, you need to stop everything you're doing now, start over, try to write much less code at a time, and *make sure everything works* before adding the next bit.

Comment: If you *do* have an answer in mind for those questions (similar ones for all the other messages that you got), then the next step is to think about that answer and compare it to the code that you have. This is how you start the [debugging](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) process. So, say you know what code is supposed to make `screen` have a value. Is that code actually written yet? If it's supposed to come from somewhere else, did you do the necessary `import`? Does the code get called? If you think it should be called but isn't, try to find out why not.

Comment: But more importantly, you should learn that when the problem is "my IDE gave me some messages that say there is a problem with my code", the first step is not "go to Stack Overflow, copy and paste the code I have, copy and paste the messages I have, and ask the question I have right now (which is "what do I do about this?")". [That is the **last** step.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592) The previous steps are to figure out [what code is relevant to the problem](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and what the real underlying question is.

Answer (score 0):

Hello sorry for everything and thanks for your answers. Fact is that only Visual Studio Code is showing these problems but the programm is working. I think there is a bibliothek not installed. But which one is not installed I need to know...

Comment: You have written this as an ANSWER. This is at most a comment!